# Can raw scallops be used as a sugar substitute?

Tags: substitutions, sugar, scallops

Raw scallops contain glycine and alanine, two amino acids that invoke the sensation of sweetness on the tongue. People's sensitivity to these compounds can differ greatly; to me scallops have a very sweet taste. Is there a way I can make the most of this in order to cut down on sugar in my diet?

Comment: Many ingredients bring sweetness to a dish, or work to counteract acidity.  They are frequently employed this way, but in this regard they are not really thought of as a sugar substitute. Your question makes me wonder in what application scallops might be employed as a sugar substitute.  I certainly would not want them in a cake.  So, a better question might specify your final product and potential sugar substitutes.

Comment: Ground, dried scallops does not sound like a winner to me, is that the kind of thing you had in mind?

Comment: What are you trying to substitute sugar *in*?

Comment: Sometimes the better questions is not 'could yo', but 'should you', TBH this sounds more like something Heston Blumenthal would try.